# How can I get the total number of items in a DynamoDB table?

Tags: php, amazon-dynamodb

I want to know how many items are in my dynamodb table. From the API guide, one way to do it is using a [scan](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/LowLevelPHPScanning.html) as follows:

```
<?php
$dynamodb = new AmazonDynamoDB();

$scan_response = $dynamodb->scan(array(
    'TableName' => 'ProductCatalog' 
));

echo "Total number of items: ".count($scan_response->body->Items)."\n";
```

However, this has to fetch all items and store them in an array in memory which isn't feasible in most cases I would presume. Is there a way to get the total item count more efficiently?

This data is not available in the AWS Dynamo web-console, I have already checked. (at first it looks like it is shown alongside the pagination buttons, but it turns out the figure grows as you go to the next page of items).

Comment: Use DescribeTable, details here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37036989/3305145

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I can think of three options to get the total number of items in a DynamoDB table.

1. The first option is using the scan, but the scan function is inefficient and is in general a bad practice, especially for tables with heavy reads or production tables.
2. The second option is what was mention by Atharva:

   > A better solution that comes to my mind is to maintain the total
   >   number of item counts for such tables in a separate table, where each
   >   item will have Table name as it's hash key and total number of items
   >   in that table as it's non-key attribute. You can then keep this Table
   >   possibly named "TotalNumberOfItemsPerTable" updated by making atomic
   >   update operations to increment/decrement the total item count for a
   >   particular table.

   The only problem this is that increment operations are not idempotent. So if a write fails or you write more than once this will be reflected in the count. If you need pin-point accuracy, use a conditional update instead.
3. The simplest solution is the DescribeTable which returns ItemCount. The only issue is that the count isn't up to date. The count is updated every 6 hours.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_DescribeTable.html

Comment: Can the `TransactWriteItems` API be used to create an atomic operation which puts to the main table and also updates the TotalNumberOfItemsPerTable table?

Answer (score 14):

The `Count` option is definitely what you want, but you also have to take into account that there may be one or more "page" of results in your Scan result. The Scan operation only scans 1MB of data in your table at a time, so the value of `Count` in the result is only going to reflect the count of the first 1MB of the table. You will need to make subsequent requests using the value of `LastEvaluatedKey` in the result (if it is there). Here is some sample code for doing something like that:

```
<?php

$dynamo_db = new AmazonDynamoDB();

$total = 0;
$start_key = null;
$params = array(
    'TableName' => 'my-table',
    'Count'     => true
);

do {
    if ($start_key) {
        $params['ExclusiveStartKey'] = $start_key->getArrayCopy();
    }

    $response = $dynamo_db->scan($params);

    if ($response->isOK()) {
        $total += (string) $response->body->Count;

        if ($response->body->LastEvaluatedKey) {
            $start_key = $response->body->LastEvaluatedKey->to_array();
        } else {
            $start_key = null;
        }
    }
} while ($start_key);

echo "Count: {$total}";
```

Answer (score 7):

Aha, there is a `Count` option in the `scan` API, see http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSSDKforPHP/latest/#m=AmazonDynamoDB/scan

```
<?php
$dynamodb = new DynamoMetadata();

$scan_response = $dynamodb->scan(array(
    'TableName' => 'ProductCatalog'
    'Count'     => true,
));

echo "Count: ".$scan_response->body->Count."\n";
```

Comment: As mentioned by Jeremy Lindblom in his answer and evidenced by this: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/QueryAndScan.html make sure you take care of the 1MB limit, i.e. the count returned can be a partial count if your table size is greater than 1MB.

Comment: Whenever I run the above code, I get the following: `Fatal error: Class 'DynamoMetadata' not found in C:\Users\Lenovo\xampp\public_html\upload_file.php on line 73`. What to do to solve it?

Answer (score 6):

If you are interested in using the total number of items in a table in your application's logic, that means you are going to query for the total counts pretty frequently. Now one way to achieve this is by using scan operation. But remember that scan operation literally scans through the whole table and therefore consumes lots of throughput, so all the query operations will receive Throttled Exception in that duration. And even considering the fact that scan will limit the resultant count by size of 1MB, you will have to make repeated scan operations to get the actual number of items if the table is very large. This will require to write a custom query logic and handle inevitable throttling in query operations.

A better solution that comes to my mind is to maintain the total number of item counts for such tables in a separate table, where each item will have Table name as it's hash key and total number of items in that table as it's non-key attribute. You can then keep this Table possibly named "TotalNumberOfItemsPerTable" updated by making atomic update operations to increment/decrement the total item count for a particular table.

No issue of throttling or 1MB limit.

Furthermore, you can expand this concept to even further granularity for example to maintain total number of items  matching with some hash key or any arbitrary criteria which you can encode in string form to make an entry in your table named something like "TotalNumberOfItemsInSomeCollection" or "TotalNumberOfItemsMatchingSomeCriteria". These tables can then contain entries for number of items per table, per collection or items matching with some criteria.

Answer (score 3):

An approximate item count value (supposedly updated every six hours) is available in the AWS console for DynamoDB. Just select the table and look under the Details tab, last entry is Item Count. If this works for you, then you can avoid consuming your table throughput to do the count.

Answer (score 1):

This is now available in the AWS table overview screen under the section 'Table details', field 'Item count'.  It appears to be just a dump of DescribeTable, and notes that its updated roughly every six hours.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I do it:

- Go into the DynamoDB console
- Select a table
- Overview (default landing for selecting a table)
- Scroll down to "Summary" section
- View 3 values that are updated "every 6 hours", count, size and average item size.
- Click on "Get Live Item Count" button
- Click "start scan"

I see the count going up (independent of the 1 MB paging limit mentioned in some answers) and see "Complete" when the live count is reached.

This consumes read capacity of a scan, so before physically doing this, it's a good idea to manually ramp up provisioned capacity to avoid throttling other current read traffic. You can "pause" the scan at will and continue (to allow provisioned capacity to build up between partial scan sessions. Eventually, you will reach the number of items in the table.

The way to do this safely so as to minimize the risk of throttling other traffic:

- increase read capacity units (either a high setting without auto scaling or setting the minimum to a high number)
- wait until the higher capacity shows up (red dot) in the read usage metric in cloudwatch or in the dynamodb console (in a tab or window separate from the "get live count" operation tab/window)
- click the scan button and wait a few seconds, then pause
- examine the increase usage (in the other tab/window) on the graph 2 minutes later to see how it affects read usage
- repeat the scan/pause procedure using timed intervals that are acceptable risk to you until the scan is complete and the result is timestamped in result
- You'll see the count total along with the date/time stamp of the completed count operation
- Write down the info, it's completely lost when you close the window!
- Reset the provisioned read capacity back to where it was to avoid incurring extra cost

Note: The same thing could work with auto scaling if you timed the scanning sessions appropriately to load the read capacity while giving time for the auto scaling to increase capacity for you (which would then drop after the scan is complete)

Another method might be to switch to ON DEMAND provisioning, do the scan above, then switch back to provisioned capacity, but I haven't tested that so am not sure if ON DEMAND would guarantee handling the required capacity requirements without throttling.

Answer (score 1):

This is an indirect answer, not a direct answer.

I wanted this count because I wanted to generate a unique ID for every item I would add to the table, in this case per-user.

Since there is no solid, reliable, bullet proof way to do this that won't risk an edge case of overwriting user data without very careful coding, I am going to opt for a different method:

1. generate a very large random number
2. check that this ID is not in use
3. if it is, generate a new very large random number (recursive)
4. once we've found an unused very large random number, use that as ID

For some people looking this up, this will provide an alternate viable solution, given that currently this functionality isn't reliably available.

Otherwise, as mentioned in the (currently) accepted answer, I think keeping a count up to date in a separate table would be the best option, but watch out and make your updates reliable and your reads dependent and always check for collisions.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I get the exact item count on my billion records DynamoDB table:

hive>

```
set dynamodb.throughput.write.percent = 1;
set dynamodb.throughput.read.percent = 1;
set hive.execution.engine = mr;
set mapreduce.reduce.speculative=false;
set mapreduce.map.speculative=false;

CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE dynamodb_table (`ID` STRING,`DateTime` STRING,`ReportedbyName` STRING,`ReportedbySurName` STRING,`Company` STRING,`Position` STRING,`Country` STRING,`MailDomain` STRING) STORED BY 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.dynamodb.DynamoDBStorageHandler' TBLPROPERTIES ("dynamodb.table.name" = "BillionData", "dynamodb.column.mapping" = "ID:ID,DateTime:DateTime,ReportedbyName:ReportedbyName,ReportedbySurName:ReportedbySurName,Company:Company,Position:Position,Country:Country,MailDomain:MailDomain");

SELECT count(*) FROM dynamodb_table;
```

*You should have a EMR cluster, which comes installed with Hive and DynamoDB record Handler.
*With this command, DynamoDB handler on the hive issues "PARALLEL SCANS" with multiple Mapreduce mappers(AKA Workers) working on different partitions to get the count. This will be much efficient and faster than normal scans.
*You must be willing to bump up Read capacity very high for certain period of time.
* On a decent sized(20 node) cluster , With 10000 RCU , it took 15 minutes to get count on billion records Approx.
* New writes on this DDB table during this period will make the count inconsistent.

Answer (score 0):

Please do not use scan method of dynamoDb because it read all data of tabel but in this case u need only count so use this .

```
$scan_response = $dynamodb->describeTable(array(
'TableName' => 'ProductCatalog' ));
```

and print this for result `$scan_response['Table']['ItemCount']`

Comment: It's not he best approach, since count may be not up to date, it's updated every 6 hours.