# DynamoDB Primary Key strategy

Tags: amazon-web-services, primary-key, amazon-dynamodb, boto3

I'm dabbling with DynamoDB (using boto3) for the first time, and I'm not sure how to define my Partition Key. I'm used to SQL, where you can use [AUTO_INCREMENT](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_autoincrement.asp) to ensure that the Key will always increase.

I haven't seen such an option in DynamoDB - instead, when using [put_item](http://boto3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/services/dynamodb.html#DynamoDB.Client.put_item), the "primary key attributes are required" - I take this to mean that I have to define the value explicitly (and, indeed, if I leave it off, I get `botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the PutItem operation: One or more parameter values were invalid: Missing the key id in the item`)

If already have rows with id 1, 2, 3, ...N, I naturally want the next row that I insert to have Primary Key N+1. But I don't know how to generate that - the solutions given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21958587/1040915) are all imperfect.

Should I be generating the Primary Key values independently, perhaps by hashing the other values of the item? If I do so, isn't there a (small) chance of hash-collision? Then again, since DynamoDB seems to determine [partition based on a hash of the Partition Key](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/HowItWorks.Partitions.html#HowItWorks.Partitions.CompositeKey), is there any reason for me not to simply use a random sufficiently-long string?

Answer (score 4):

DynamoDb does not support generated keys, you have to specify one yourself. You can't reliably generate sequential IDs.

One common way is instead to use UUIDs.

Comment: Thanks! So, if the Primary Key is an essentially-random value, what purpose does it serve? Why doesn't DyanmoDB generate it itself - or, to put it another way, how does it benefit me to know/determine in advance the Primary Key of an item?

Comment: I think that is a technical decision, seeing as it is a distributed data store. I'm only guessing now, but deciding the next number in a sequential series would be a bottleneck when the data is shared (spread across multiple instances). All would have to share the one counter.

Comment: I agree with DanneJ. Although, if you, insist to implement sequential series without a bottleneck, but with a little bit of latency addendum, I suggest that you try using http://www.stateful.co/. It's an open sourced atomic counters service.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem while working through the [Build a basic Web Application](https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/hands-on/build-web-app-s3-lambda-api-gateway-dynamodb) tutorial.

In module 4 of the tutorial, after modifying the lambda function to write to the DynamoDB table, I had to change `ID` to `Id` in the line marked **THIS LINE** (see below) after which the test worked.

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
# extract values from the event object we got from the Lambda service and store in a variable
    name = event['firstName'] +' '+ event['lastName']
# write name and time to the DynamoDB table using the object we instantiated and save response in a variable
    response = table.put_item(
        Item={
            'ID': name,   <- THIS LINE
            'LatestGreetingTime':now
            })
# return a properly formatted JSON object
    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': json.dumps('Hello from Lambda, ' + name)
    }
```

I also had to edit my test input to include a random uuid as shown:

```
{
  "Id": "560e2227-c738-41d9-ad5a-bcad6a3bc273",
  "firstName": "Ada",
  "lastName": "Lovelace"
}
```