# How to get the item count on a DynamoDB table using PHP in real-time?

Tags: php, count, amazon-dynamodb, real-time, obsolete

I have a table in Amazon DynamoDB. I want to get the number of items in the table using PHP script.

Now, **I know** that there are a lot of questions about this topic, but they are all obsolete, and the solutions use an out-of-date APIs.

I tried running this code, but probably, as I said, it uses an out-of-date API, since it can't find the class:

```
$dynamodb = new DynamoMetadata();

$scan_response = $dynamodb->scan(array(
    'TableName' => 'Table',
    'Count' => true
));

echo "Count: ".$scan_response->body->Count."\n";
```

I also tried with this, but again, it couldn't find the class:

```
$dynamodb = new AmazonDynamoDB();
```

I also tried using `describeTable`, to get `ItemCount`, but this number isn't updated. It gets updated only every 6 hours.

Is there a way so I could view the number of of items in the table in real-time?

Comment: Did you refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12499822/how-can-i-get-the-total-number-of-items-in-a-dynamodb-table?

Comment: @notionquest Yes, I did refer that, but there is no suitable information for me. The `DescribeTable` option isn't relevant for me, since I need the updated count. I didn't understand how to use the other methods in the accepted answer. Could you please help me figure out what to do?

Comment: Is there any way to get the item count from the table in real-time?

Comment: No,there is no way other than scanning and counting the items.

Comment: @notionquest Can you please help me write the code? I'm not sure how to write it... Using a loop maybe... Not so sure...

Answer (score 2):

Following solution helped me to get counts using php7 and AWS SDK v3:

```
<?php
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use Aws\S3\S3Client;

use Aws\DynamoDb\Exception\DynamoDbException;

$sharedConfig = [
    'region' => 'us-east-1',
    'version' => 'latest',
    'DynamoDb' => [
        'region' => 'us-east-1'
    ]
];

$sdk = new Aws\Sdk($sharedConfig);

$client = $sdk->createDynamoDb();
$tableName = '<TABLE NAME>';

$params = [
    'TableName' => $tableName,
    'Select' => 'COUNT'
];
try {
    $result = $client->scan($params);
    $count = current($result)['Count'];
    echo $count;
} catch (DynamoDbException $e) {
    echo "Unable to query:\n";
    echo $e->getMessage() . "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So, I found a solution:

```
$result = $client->describeTable(array(
    'TableName' => 'errors'
));

// The result of an operation can be used like an array
echo $result['Table']['ItemCount'] . "\n";
```

But this is not what I wanted...

I need a solution that will show me the number in real-time and not the number which was true 6 hours ago...

Comment: From API reference doc, ItemCount — (Integer)
The number of items in the specified table. DynamoDB updates this value approximately every six hours. Recent changes might not be reflected in this value.

Comment: @notionquest, OK, so is there another way which is updated real-time?