# how to get total row count in dynamodb?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

In MySQL total number of rows found using "select count(*) from **TABLENAME**".

Similarly, how to get total number of rows in dynamodb table. using metrics is possible to know total number of rows.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I get the total number of items in a DynamoDB table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12499822/how-can-i-get-the-total-number-of-items-in-a-dynamodb-table)

Comment: how can i get today or particular date added records count only

Answer (score 3):

If you just want to know the count, and don't need the number programmatically, go into the DynamoDB console, click on the table, and it will show you the item count

[image]

Comment: note the count shown is roughly 6hrs behind (fine print out the bottom) "live count" can be done to update the count...but it runs a scan and consumes RCU

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind a count that's roughly 6 hours behind, then Stu's answer works.  IIRC, it's available programmatically also.

But if you want real-time counts, re-think your need for them ;)

If you really, really, need them, configure a DDB stream to a lambda that will update another DDB table (or a row in the table in question) with the record count and any other aggregate info you want to track.  A GSI is often useful here as discussed in [Using Global Secondary Indexes for Materialized Aggregation Queries](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/bp-gsi-aggregation.html)